# Copy and paste cells after Filter

Tags: excel, vba, copy, autofilter

I have some values in column A where they include the negative and positive values and where i wrote the below one to filter and copy the same in adjacent column.

But i require is After filtering if a3, a7, a8 are having negative values they should copy to adjacent cells that is b3, b7, b8.Am unable to get it.

Please help........

```
Sub AutoFilter_in_Excel()
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<0", Operator:=xlAnd
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A7").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range("c2")
Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlAnd
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:A7").Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("sheet1").Range("b2")
End Sub
```

Comment: This could easily be done with formulas and an IF, why force it into VBA?

Answer (score 0):

This will do it. The issue you have is that you can't copy ranges with multiple areas across.

```
Sub AutoFilter_in_Excel()
Dim rg As Range

With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<0"

    For Each rg In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas

        rg.Copy rg.Offset(, 1)

    Next rg

End With

End Sub
```